# input box generate on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am generating a dynamic Input box with radio button selection.
I am doing but problem is there.

I am trying to generate only one input box on every last radio button.

**Problem**: when i have clicked on radio button one time then Why input box is generating more than 1.

**jsfiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/4A4FY/

**Jquery**

```
  $("input[data-target='generateInput']").on('click', function (e) {
        var targetId = $(this).parent("div").attr("id");
        var t = $("div#input_" + targetId).append("<input type='text' name='aa' />");
    });
```

**HTML**

```
    <select id="e1" name='selectTag' multiple>
     <option value="ABC" data-id='1' id='1'>ABC</option>
     <option value="DEF" data-id='2' id='2'>DEF</option>
     <option value="GHI" data-id='3' id='3'>GHI</option>
     <option value="JKL" data-id='4' id='4'>JKL</option>
     <option value="MNO" data-id='5' id='5'>MNO</option>
   </select>
   <div id='generate' style='margin:10px;'></div>
```

Comment: I'm somewhat confused this does work but what id $('div#input_id') that's not in the markup at all?

Comment: Where is `div#input_id`? And how are you appending it to every `div#input_id`? There should only be one?

Comment: There is no `div` with `id="input_id"` in your HTML. Where should it be appended?

Comment: Sorry your explanation is still unclear and open to many interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the event handler `change` and check against all inputs

```
$('input').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).data('i') == 3){
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of the selected radio button

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            $("input[name='radioBtn_4']").on('click', function(e) {
                if($(e.currentTarget).val()==="Radio 3")   {
                    var t = $('div#4').append("<input type='text' name='aa' />"); 
                } else{
                    $("input[name='aa']").remove();
                }

            });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are adding event handler for every `click`. Means your code execute with every click on radio-button. you must try to bind the event handler for first click.

I suggest you to use Jquery `.one()` method. It's attach the event handler one once.

Try jquery [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method.

```
$("input[data-target='generateInput']").one('click', function(e) {
     var targetId= $(this).parent("div").attr("id");
     console.log("#input_"+targetId);
     var t = $("div#input_"+targetId).append("<input type='text' name='aa' />"); 
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4A4FY/4/)